# PHP CLI: remove last element from ARGV

Tags: php, argv

I am not sure if this is possible, but I need to make a dirty hack.
Assume I am invoking php from cli

```
php script.php one two
```

then in script.php I am doing something with `two` parameter, and then I would like to remove it, so the third party code that is included later on thought, that the initial command was

```
php script.php one
```

I tried `unset($argv[2])` and `unset($GLOBALS['argv'][2])` but this does not work. Is it after all possible what I am trying to do ?

UPDATE:
Does not work = I get exception from third party code "Too many arguments"

UPDATE: of course it should be argv[1], but it is a typo only in this question, not in the actual problem. Please assume I have written argv[1] :)

Comment: What does 'does not work' mean?

Comment: It does seem to be working for me, `unset()` -ing or `array_pop()` both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manipulating $argc and $argv from within a php script is not possible AFAIK. This is because the values are not part of the script itself, but defined in the calling scope.

As an alternative you could copy the array, pop the last argument and call the "third party code" by using exec() or system() and handing over the reduced copy.

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to remove the third element with `unset($argv[2])`.

Array are zero-based. So to remove the second element use:

> `unset($argv[1])`

Comment: hehe that's right, I made a typo in the question, but not in the actual problem. I have to pass few parameters in a real code and I am sure I did not make off-by-one mistake in the real case :) was using var dump for debugging, ensuring it disappeared from array, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the values of the variables:

- `$argv`
- `$argc`
- `$_SERVER['argv']`
- `$_SERVER['argc']`
- `$GLOBALS['argv']`
- `$GLOBALS['argc']`

This may influence code written in PHP that relies on this variables. (And this might be already what you want).

I found no way to change argv and argc under the hood in a way that the behaviour of PHP internal functions like `getopt()` can be influenced.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could ofc alter this if you wish.

I use this code for a cli script I'm running

```php
foreach( $argv as $key => $arg )
  if( $arg == '-s' )
  {
    $s = $argv[ ++$key ];
    unset( $argv[   $key ], $_SERVER[ 'argv' ][ $key ] );
    unset( $argv[ --$key ], $_SERVER[ 'argv' ][ $key ] );
    $argv = array_values( $argv );
    $_SERVER[ 'argc' ]--;
    break;
  }
```